# Firefox and chrome default border

Tags: html, css

Firefox and chrome add a border or margin around all the elements in body

How can I remove this white border or margin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just put this in your css

```
*{
border: none;
margin: 0;
padding : 0;
}
```

or

```
body{
border: none;
margin: 0;
padding : 0;
}
```

this will remove all the border, padding and margins from the main body.

Answer (score 0):

```
*{border:none;margin:0;}
```

or u can use [resetCss](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/)